# Returning a regex output to the first case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have a PHP regex which creates some HTML-tags according some pattern. Here is my code:

```
$newstr = preg_replace(
  array('/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/', '/\*(.*?)\*/', '/--(.*?)--/'  , '/`(.*?)`/'       ),
  array( "<b>$1</b>"     , "<i>$1</i>"  , "<del>$1</del>", "<code>$1</code>" ),
  $str
);
```

Also here is a **example:**

```
$str = "`this` *is* **a** --test--";
//= <code>this</code> <i>is</i> <b>a</b> <del>test</del>
```

---

Now I want to return the result of that regex to the first shape using JavaScript *(or jQuery)*. I mean is something like this:

```
var str = "<code>this</code> <i>is</i> <b>a</b> <del>test</del>";
```

I want this

```
var newstr = '`this` *is* **a** --test--';
```

How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** Here is a demo

```js
$(function () {
   var str = '<code>this</code> <i>is</i> <b>a</b> <del>test</del>';
   var r = str.replace(/<\/?code>/g, '`').replace(/<\/?i>/g, '*').replace(/<\/?b>/g, '**').replace(/<\/?del>/g, '--');
    $("body").append(r);
});
```

Comment: `var str = '<?php echo $newstr; ?>';`

Comment: @AbraCadaver No No, I get this variable `<code>this</code> <i>is</i> <b>a</b> <del>test</del>` from the content of page. I mentioned to that regex just for telling you how I have made those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var r = str.replace(/<\/?code>/g, '`').replace(/<\/?i>/g, '*').replace(/<\/?b>/g, '**').replace(/<\/?del>/g, '--')
//=> `this` *is* **a** --test--
```

Comment: Perfect ...! Thanks. +1

Comment: Just one thing, What is that modifier? in this case `g` ..! I saw elsewhere sometimes `i`, and sometimes `u`.. What are they?

Comment: `g` is for `global` replacement and `i` is for `ignore case`. I don't think JS regex has `u` (unicode)

Comment: I see, and yes I saw `u` in a PHP regex.

Comment: Well I'm trying to use of your solution, but it doesn't work ..! Your algorithm seems correct. But I don't know why it doesn't work? I updated my question and added a fiddle

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Are you see anything in the output?

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding what you're asking for, but it sounds like you want simple string replacement:

```
var str = "<code>this</code> <i>is</i> <b>a</b> <del>test</del>";
var newstr = str.replace( "<code>", "`" );
var newstr = newstr.replace( "</code>", "`" );
var newstr = newstr.replace( "<i>", "*" );
var newstr = newstr.replace( "</i>", "*" );
```

and so on.

Comment: That's correct ...! Also I think you can just define a variable one time using `var` ...! btw I think overwriting on on variable isn't a good idea. Anyway +1 for your try `:-)`